# Filter two consecutive row numbers in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I am using this code to find duplicates

### Code:

```
select donrId,
    donrFirstName,
    donrLastName,
    donrBirthDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (
        partition by donrFirstName,
        donrBirthDate order by donrLastName
        ) as SequenceNumber
from donors ) as dd
where dd.SequenceNumber > 1
order by donrId
```

### Problem:

I can't filter the partitioned result set on two consecutive numbers e.g 1 and 2

### Desired Result:

```
donrFirstName   |donrLastName  |donrBirthDate   |SequenceNumber 
---------------------------------------------------------------
king            |kong          |25/05/2017      |1
king            |kong          |25/05/2017      |2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will return only the records with sequence number > 1. To return all records starting with the number 1 you can use `COUNT(*)` window function, like this:

```
SELECT 
    donrId, donrFirstName, donrLastName, donrBirthDate, SequenceNumber
FROM
    (SELECT 
         donrId, donrFirstName, donrLastName, donrBirthDate, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY donrFirstName, donrBirthDate ORDER BY donrLastName) AS SequenceNumber 
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY donrFirstName, donrBirthDate) AS cnt
     FROM 
         donors) AS dd 
WHERE 
    dd.cnt > 1 
ORDER BY 
    donrId
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it seems to work fine but one stupid question here if I use order by in  

`Code`
COUNT(*) over (partition by donrFirstName, donrBirthDate **order by** donrFirstName )

it throws error do you know why?

Comment: What happens when you COUNT(*) over (partition by donrFirstName, donrBirthDate order by donrLastName )?

Comment: I think order by is not supported for earlier versions of SQL (like 2008); the later versions should support it. Anyway, there should not be any difference in my opinion, as the count() should not change with the order of counting